# Proper use of ctypes to call _Py_Mangle?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, ctypes, name-mangling

While sitting on a mushroom and contemplating the intricacies of inscribing a function to implement Python's name mangling algorithm, a stupendously better idea came into my noggin. Why not use the recipe already crafted into the language to accomplish such a goal? So I pulled `ctypes` out of my satchel to help with the endeavor and executed `ctypes.pythonapi._Py_Mangle('Demo', '__test')`. Lo and behold, an error appeared out of thin air saying `OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000A65646F00A8` and did not bother to explain the conundrum any more than that.

The full interaction with the interpreter is as follows:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.pythonapi._Py_Mangle('Demo', '__test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    ctypes.pythonapi._Py_Mangle('Demo', '__test')
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000A65646F00A8
```

Does anyone know what needs to be changed in order to call the mangling function successfully?

Comment: `pythonapi` is an instance of `PyDLL`, which is a subclass of `CDLL` that sets a flag on function pointers to prevent releasing the global interpreter lock (GIL) during a call. Otherwise the default argument conversions and result type are the same as `CDLL`. Thus you need to define the types: `ctypes.pythonapi._Py_Mangle.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object, ctypes.py_object];` `ctypes.pythonapi._Py_Mangle.restype = ctypes.py_object`.

Comment: FYI, this won't help if your code has to run on PyPy, Jython, or IronPython. Really there should be a `sys.name_mangle` or `inspect.name_mangle` to do this for you.

Comment: @eryksun: Is there a feature request or PEP for that?  Or at least a `python-ideas` discussion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to comments by [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun), the answer to the problem is rather simple:

```
>>> from ctypes import pythonapi, py_object
>>> py_mangle = pythonapi._Py_Mangle
>>> py_mangle.argtypes = py_object, py_object
>>> py_mangle.restype = py_object
>>> py_mangle('Demo', '__test')
'_Demo__test'
```