# How to improve a mixin structure in Python?

Tags: python, mixins

I have a simple mixin structure in Python. The code should be pretty self-explaining:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class MixinA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 1
    def a(self):
        print('A: x = ' + str(self.x) + ', y = ' + str(self.y))

class MixinB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2
        self.z = 3
    def b(self):
        print('B: x = ' + str(self.x) + ', z = ' + str(self.z))

class MyFirstMix(MixinA, MixinB, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
        MixinB.__init__(self)
        MixinA.__init__(self)

class MySecondMix(MixinA, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
        MixinA.__init__(self)
```

I'd like to improve this a bit, so this leads to 3 questions/problems:

1. `MixinA` and `MixinB` both have a member `x`. Is there a way to make sure, each of the class sees only its own x`?` As far as I know: No, there isn't.
2. It's slightly cumbersome to call the constructor for each mixin in the mixed class. Is there a way to automatically call all constructors or to do something with the same effect?
3. Is there a way to dynamically mixin something in-line, without explicitly creating a class? I'm looking for a syntax like: `mix = Base() with MixinA`

If my proposed structure is completely wrong, I'm also open for other recommendations on how to handle mixins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent function overriding in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948873/prevent-function-overriding-in-python). You can prevent an instance attribute from being overridden using similar techniques mentioned there.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: So then, what's with questions 2 and 3?

Comment: Those could and probably should be posted as separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

For python class inherent, I believe there are some tricks you need to know:

1. Class in python2 and python3 are quite different.
   Python2 support old-style class, but python3 support new-style class only. Simply speaking: in python3, classes always inherent from a base class `object`, even though you do not explicitly use it. Check [Difference-between-Old-New-Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python).
2. Method Resolution Order (MRO). This determines how derived class search inherent members and functions. See [MRO](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html)
3. `super` function. Combined with MRO, you can easily call parent member or function, without explicitly know the name of parent class. See [Super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607186/how-does-pythons-super-do-the-right-thing)

Now comes to you questions:

1. MixinA and MixinB both have a member x. Is there a way to make sure, each of the class sees only its own x?

I don't quit understand your meaning. When you refer a class member, you must refer it through its instance or class. So `instance_of_MixinA.x` and `instance_of_MixinB.x` are separated. If you are talking about class `MyFirstMix(MixinA, MixinB, Base)`, it depends on how `__init__` function is called. In your code, you first populate `x` by `MixinB` and then reset its value by `MixinA`.

2. It's slightly cumbersome to call the constructor for each mixin in the mixed class. Is there a way to automatically call all constructors or to do something with the same effect.

Your designation make it impossible. You have to call all constructors.

3. Is there a way to dynamically mixin something in-line, without explicitly creating a class?

I am not sure. But I can give you some suggestions: try outside `__init__` members when def class (python3, if you used python2 take care of `super`):

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class MixinA:
    x = 0
    y = 1


class MixinB:
    x = 2
    z = 3

    def b(self):
        print('B: x = ' + str(self.x) + ', z = ' + str(self.z))


class MyFirstMix(MixinA, MixinB, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class MySecondMix(MixinA, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

The variables outside `__init__` behaves quit different from inside variables: outside variables belongs to class and will be populated for all instances of this class, while inside variables belongs only to instance (referred by `self` when you define class), and will be populated only if `__init__` is called. That's why you cannot use `super` to call all the constructors---`super` only call the priority parent's `__init__`. See [variables-outsite-inside-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function)

This is a good solution to Mixin class. In above code, `MyFirstMix` inherents both `MixinA` and `MixinB` whose members are all class members (outside `__init__`). So instances of `MyFirstMix` will inherent all class members of `MixinA` and `MixinB` without call `__init__`. Here `MixinA` and `MixinB` own same class member `x`, but the `MRO` determines that when instances of `MyFirstMix` refer `x`, `x` from `MixinA` should be returned.

Hope this will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When your inheritance schemes start to suffer from these sorts of issues it's time to consider using a technique called *composition* instead. A good readable introduction to the topic [here](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose). The [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is a bit less accessible, but also useful if you can handle the other programming languages. [This StackExchange question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance) also offers useful discussion.

At its simplest, rather than a class inheriting from `SomeParent` and mixing in the `Mixin` class, you instead have the `SomeParent` instances each create an instance of `Mixin` and use that to access the mixin class's functionality.